# Taking the geometric derivative of $e^{\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]}$

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, noncommutative-algebra, geometric-algebras

As in the title: I'm looking to take the geometric derivative with respect to $\vec{x}$ of the exponential of the commutator of $\gamma_0 \vec{k}$ and $\vec{x} \gamma^0$:
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]}$$
I'm working in the spacetime algebra (East Coast metric, if we need to pick a sign), so the $\gamma_\mu$ terms obey the following rules:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu + \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu\right] = \eta_{\mu\nu}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma^\mu \gamma_\nu + \gamma_\nu \gamma^\mu\right] = \delta^\mu_\nu
$$

The reason I'm asking here is to avoid any pitfalls that may arise from misapplication of the chain rule for a noncommutative algebra. I realize that one possible approach for evaluating this derivative is to expand it as a Taylor series:
$$
e^{\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]^n}{2^n n!}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla e^{\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]}
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]^n}{2^n (n - 1)!}
\\\\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]^{n+1}}{2^{n+1} n!}
\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\gamma_0 \vec{k} \vec{x} \gamma^0 - \vec{x} \gamma^0 \gamma_0 \vec{k}\right]^{n+1}}{2^n n!}
\end{align}
$$
But I don't know if I can pull the commutator expression as a term on the left, on the right, or if it's irrelevant, so I can reduce its exponent.

[edit] I'm not considering this question answered yet, but I just realized for each exponential term, it technically shouldn't matter if we pull a term out on one side or the other, as long as we do it consistently. That being said, I am wary of geometric consequences of the choice of left vs. right multiplication.

Comment: Do you mean for $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{x}$ to be considered spatial vectors (i.e.: STA bivectors: $\vec{x} = \gamma_k \gamma_0 x^k$), or four vectors ($\vec{x} = \gamma_\mu x^\mu$)?

Comment: $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{x}$ are intended to be spacetime four-vectors which are explicitly spacetime split by $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma^0$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\renewcommand\vec\mathbf
\newcommand\swedge{\mathop{\underset S\wedge}}
\newcommand\slcontr{\mathop{\underset S\rfloor}}
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
$I don't know which one is the "East coast" metric,
though it doesn't matter that much.
I also assume that $k,x$ are spacetime 4-vectors.

Throughout I will use the convention that the geometric product
has less precedence than any other product,
i.e. you always do geometric products last.
I will also use the convention that the contraction $\lcontr$
has lower precedence than $\wedge$ and $\times$ so that e.g.
$$
  A\lcontr B\wedge C = A\lcontr(B\wedge C).
$$

Note that $\gamma^0 = \iota\gamma_0$ where $\iota = \pm1$
depending on signature.

We can compute this in closed form.
They key is understanding the relationship between the spacetime algebra (STA)
and its *even subalgebra* which is isomorphic to the geometric algebra
of 3D Euclidean space, and is the natural way
of representing spatial quantities in STA.
(As such, I will call it the *spatial subalgebra*.)
We define
$$
  \vec x = x\wedge\gamma^0,\quad \vec k = k\wedge\gamma^0
$$
which is the spatial part of the *spacetime split*
$$
  x\gamma^0 = x\cdot\gamma^0 + \vec x
$$
with $x\cdot\gamma^0$ being the time component and $\vec x$
representing a spatial vector in the spatial subalgebra.

Because scalars commute with everything,
only the spatial parts matter in the commutator, yielding
$$
  X := \frac12[\gamma_0k, x\gamma^0] = \frac12\iota[\vec x, \vec k]
    = \iota\vec x\times\vec k
$$
where the *commutator product* $\times$ is half the commutator,
but overall a more meaningful operation.
The quantity $\vec x\times\vec k$
is exactly the *spatial* wedge product of spatial vectors,
yielding a *spatial bivector* (which is also a spacetime bivector).
It immediately follows that
$$
  e^X = \cos|X| + X'\sin|X|
$$
where $|X| = \sqrt{-X^2}$ and $X' = X/|X|$.
To differentiate this,
we reference Chapter 2 of *Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus* (CAGC)
by David Hestenes and Garret Sobczyk.
The chain rule gives us
$$
  \nabla e^X = \dot\nabla\dot X\cdot\partial_X e^X
$$
where $\partial_X$ is the spatial bivector derivative
and $A\cdot B = \langle AB\rangle_0$ is the scalar product.
The overdots specify that $\dot\nabla$ is only differentiating $\dot X$.
Now we get three terms, use the chain rule again on the trig functions,
and apply basic identities from CAGC:
$$\begin{aligned}
  \dot X\cdot\partial_X e^X
  &=
    {-(\dot X\cdot\partial_X|X|)}\sin|X|
    + \left(\dot X\cdot\partial_XX'\right)\sin|X|
    + X'(\dot X\cdot\partial_X|X|)\cos|X|.
\\
  &=
    \dot X\cdot X'\sin|X|
    + \frac1{|X|}\left(\dot X + \dot X\cdot X'X'\right)\sin|X|
    - X'\dot X\cdot X'\cos|X|.
\end{aligned}$$
We now need to apply $\dot\nabla$ to this.
We need two subexpressions
$$
  \dot\nabla\dot X\cdot X'\quad\text{and}\quad\dot\nabla\dot X
$$

For the first, if we use
$$
  \swedge\quad\text{and}\quad\slcontr
$$
to represent the **spatial** wedge product and **spatial** left contraction
and note that the spatial subalgebra has the same scalar product
as the whole spacetime algebra, then
$$\begin{aligned}
  \dot\nabla\dot X\cdot X'
  &= \dot\nabla\bigl[(\dot x\wedge\gamma_0)\swedge\vec k\bigr]\cdot X'
\\
  &= \dot\nabla(\dot x\wedge\gamma_0)\cdot(\vec k\slcontr X')
\\
 &= \dot\nabla\dot x\cdot[\gamma_0\lcontr\vec k\times X']
\\
 &= \gamma_0\lcontr\vec k\times X'.
\end{aligned}$$
The key is that
$$
  \vec x\times\vec k = \vec x\swedge\vec k
$$
and that, because $X'$ is a spatial bivector, the quantity
$$
  \vec k\slcontr X' = \vec k\times X'
$$
is a spatial vector.
Note that $\iota\vec x = x\wedge\gamma_0$,
and that in the third and fourth lines we use the spacetime contraction.

For the second, we see
$$\begin{aligned}
  \dot\nabla(\dot x\wedge\gamma_0)\times\vec k
  &= \dot\nabla\bigl[\dot x\wedge(\gamma_0\times\vec k) + (\dot x\times\vec k)\wedge\gamma_0\bigr]
\\
  &= 3\gamma_0\lcontr\vec k + \dot\nabla(\dot x\lcontr k\wedge\gamma^0)\wedge\gamma_0
\\
  &= 3\gamma_0\vec k - \dot\nabla\dot x\cdot\gamma^0 k\wedge\gamma_0
\\
  &= 3\gamma_0\vec k - \gamma_0\vec k
\\
  &= 2\gamma_0\vec k.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $\gamma_0\times\vec k = \gamma_0\lcontr\vec k = \gamma_0\vec k$.

All together (and replacing $X'$ with $X/|X|$) we now have
$$
  \nabla e^X
  = \frac{\sin|X|}{|X|}\gamma_0\lcontr\vec k\times X
    + \frac{2\sin|X|}{|X|}\gamma_0\vec k
    + \frac{\sin|X|-|X|\cos|X|}{|X|^3}\gamma_0\lcontr\vec k\times XX.
$$
To simplify, we first start with
$$\begin{aligned}
  \gamma_0\lcontr\vec k\times X
  &= \gamma_0\lcontr\bigl[\iota\vec k\slcontr\vec x\swedge\vec k\bigr]
  = \gamma_0\lcontr\bigl[\iota\vec k\cdot\vec x\,\vec k - \iota\vec k^2\vec x\bigr]
\\
  &= \iota\vec k\cdot\vec x\,\gamma_0\vec k - \iota\vec k^2\gamma_0\vec x.
\end{aligned}$$
We then also multiply by $X$; since
$$
  \iota\vec kX
  = \vec k\slcontr\vec x\swedge\vec k + \vec k\swedge\vec x\swedge\vec k
  = \vec k\cdot\vec x\,\vec k - \vec k^2\vec x,
$$
$$
  \iota\vec xX
  = \vec x\slcontr\vec x\wedge\vec k + \vec x\swedge\vec x\swedge\vec k
  = \vec x^2\vec k - \vec x\cdot\vec k\,\vec x
$$
we see
$$\begin{aligned}
  \gamma_0\lcontr\vec k\times XX
  &= (\vec k\cdot\vec x)^2\gamma_0\vec k - \vec k\cdot\vec x\,\vec k^2\gamma_0\vec x
    - \vec x^2\vec k^2\gamma_0\vec k + \vec x\cdot\vec k\,\vec k^2\gamma_0\vec x
\\
  &= \bigl[(\vec k\cdot\vec x)^2-\vec k^2\vec x^2\bigr]\gamma_0\vec k
\\
  &= -|X|^2\gamma_0\vec k
\end{aligned}$$

The quantities $\vec x\gamma_0 = -\gamma_0\vec x$ and $\vec k\gamma_0 = -\gamma_0\vec k$ are more natural since e.g. $\vec x\gamma_0 = x - x\cdot\gamma^0\gamma_0$ is exactly the spacetime vector representation of the spatial vector $\vec x$. Finally, we have
$$
  \nabla e^X
    = \iota S\vec k^2\vec x\gamma_0
      -\Bigl[\iota S\vec k\cdot\vec x + S + \cos|X|\Bigr]\vec k\gamma_0,
\tag{$*$}
$$
$$
  |X| = \sqrt{\vec k^2\vec x^2 - (\vec k\cdot\vec x)^2},\quad S = \frac{\sin|X|}{|X|}.
$$

This has all been assuming $|X| \ne 0$. When $|X| \approx 0$ we instead see that
$$
  \nabla e^X \approx \nabla(1 + X) = \nabla X = 2\gamma_0\vec k.
\tag{$**$}
$$
For $|X| \approx 0$ to be true, either $|\vec k| \approx 0$
or there is a scalar $a$ (dependent on $x$)
such that $\vec x \approx a\vec k$.
When $\vec k = 0$ we see that ($*$) and ($**$) agree.
When $\vec x \approx a\vec k$, we approximate ($*$) as
$$
  \nabla e^X \approx \iota a\vec k^3\gamma_0 - [\iota a\vec k^2 + 1]\vec k\gamma_0 = \gamma_0\vec k
$$
which is inconsistent with ($**$),
though perhaps merely an indication that I've made a mistake somewhere.
If this is not a mistake, then that means we should restrict to
$|X| > 0$.

Comment: The East Coast metric is the mostly plusses signature, so $(\gamma_0)^2 = -c^2$.

Comment: @brainandforce Ok. I should note that I made the assumption that $\gamma_0^2 = \pm1$ rather than $\pm c^2$.